# How to convert a list into a string in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How do you convert a list into a string? I am trying to use parse-int to take a list of numbers and convert them to decimal, but i end up getting an error saying "The control-string must be a string, not (contents)".
I'm using format, but I'm not sure if I'm using it incorrectly.

Here's my code:

```
    (princ "Enter a or list of hexadecimal numbers: ")
    (setq numList (read-from-string (concatenate 'string "(" (read-line) ")")))
    (defun hextodec(nums)
            (setq  numString (format "%s" nums))
            (setq newNum (parse-integer numString :radix 16))
            (write nums)
            (princ " = ")
            (write newNum)
    ) ;This will format the number that the user enters
    (hextodec numList)
```

Comment: "%s" is not valid in Lisp. You also use a lot of undeclared variables like numList, numString, newNum. You also miss to clear the output buffer after printing. See FINISH-OUTPUT.

Comment: The basic string printing directive is `~a` (aesthetics). [basic string formatting](https://vindarel.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html#string-formatting).

Comment: Maybe you are accustomed to Clojure's format? As others have noted, Lisp format (and the Clojure cl-format function from the pretty-print module) would be (format nil "~s"). On a different issue, it seems hextodec thinks its input is a list in one place and a single hex string in another place.

Comment: @RainerJoswig `"%s"` is not valid in Common Lisp's `format`, but it's valid in Emacs Lisp's `format`. However, this is tagged `common-lisp`, so that seems rather moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `read-from-string` anyway, you can just tell Lisp's reader to read base 16 integers:

```
;; CLISP session
[1]> (let ((*read-base* 16)) (read-from-string "(9 A B C F 10)"))
(9 10 11 12 15 16) ;
14
```

`read-from-string` is a potential security hole if the contents of the string are untrusted input, because of the hash-dot evaluation notation.

When using the Lisp reader on untrusted data, be sure bind `*read-eval*` to `nil`.

```
[2]> (read-from-string "(#.(+ 2 2))")
(4) ;
11
```

Note how the `#.` notation causes the `+` function specified in the string data to be executed. That could be any function, such as something that whacks files in your filesystem, or sends sensitive data to a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

`Format`'s first argument is the stream to print to.  You seem to intend to return the string instead of printing, so you should put `nil` there: `(format nil "~s" nums)`

The format control string `"%s"` does not contain any format directives.  The entire `format` form does not make much sense here, as you seem to intend to loop over the given `nums` instead.  You should employ some looping construct for that, e. g. `loop`, `do`, `map`, `mapcar` ….